# I'm using c# and mono and trying to play simple video file from my android but it dosent work

Tags: c#, mono

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Media;

namespace MoviePlayer
{
    [Activity(Label = "MoviePlayer", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;
        MediaPlayer mp;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            mp = new MediaPlayer();
            mp.Prepare();
            mp.SetDataSource()
            mp.Start();

        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what should be in the mp.SetDataSource()
I looked on examples but didn't understand.

Comment: its not working because you have not given a media file to the MediaPlayer to play

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a path to the file you want to play as a `string` to the [**`SetDataSource()`**](http://docs.mono-android.net/Android.Media.MediaPlayer.SetDataSource%28System.String%29) method to play that file.

[Mono Documentation](http://docs.mono-android.net/Android.Media.MediaPlayer.SetDataSource%28System.String%29)

[Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: The link to the mono docs is since broken, but more info can be found here now: http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/media/video/play_video and here http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aAndroid.Media.MediaPlayer